# Is it legal to use an operator in a fold expression that was introduced by a using declaration?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, fold-expression

I was experimenting with using arbitrary functions in fold expressions, when I found the following code that compiles with `gcc` but does not compile with `clang`.

```cpp
enum Enum {
    A = 3,
    B = 8,
    C = 5
};

namespace EnumMax {
    constexpr Enum operator>>=(const Enum left, const Enum right) {
        return left < right ? right : left;
    }
}

template<Enum ... enums>
constexpr Enum max() {
    using EnumMax::operator>>=;
    return (enums >>= ...);
}

constexpr Enum max_v = max<A, B, C>();
```

https://godbolt.org/z/-LOudM

It seems that `clang` does not consider the overloaded operator, but attempts to use the regular `>>=` operator in the fold expression.

However, if instead the fold expression is spelled out, `clang` does consider the overloaded operator and will compile just fine:

```cpp
constexpr Enum maxExplicit() {
    using EnumMax::operator>>=;
    return (A >>= (B >>= C));
}
```

Is this a `clang` bug? Or is the spelled out equivalent of a fold expression not exactly equivalent?

Comment: For reference: MSVC compiles your code as well: https://godbolt.org/z/UXPiur

Comment: Posting as comment because I am not 100% certain, but it does look like a bug, as the standard makes no special handling of operators in fold expressions. Might be worth opening a ticket on clang issue tracker.

Comment: Filed [42518](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42518), your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [[expr.prim.fold]/*fold-operator*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.fold#nt:fold-operator):

> *fold-operator:* one of
>
> ```
> +   -   *   /   %   ^   &   |   <<   >> 
> +=  -=  *=  /=  %=  ^=  &=  |=  <<=  >>=  =
> ==  !=  <   >   <=  >=  &&  ||  ,    .*   ->*
> ```

So `>>=` is a *fold-operator*.

Per [[expr.prim.fold]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.fold#2):

> An expression of the form `(... op e)` where *`op`* is a
>   *fold-operator* is called a *unary left fold*. An expression of the form `(e op ...)` where *`op`* is a *fold-operator* is
>   called a *unary right fold*. Unary left folds and unary right folds
>   are collectively called *unary folds*. In a unary fold, the
>   *cast-expression* shall contain an unexpanded pack ([temp.variadic]).

So `(enums >>= ...)` is a unary right fold.

Per [[temp.variadic]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#10):

> The instantiation of a *fold-expression* produces:
>
> - [...]
> - `E1 op (⋯ op (EN−1 op EN))` for a unary right fold,
> - [...]
>
> In each case, *`op`* is the *fold-operator*, *`N`* is the number of
>   elements in the pack expansion parameters, and each
>   `Ei` is generated by instantiating the pattern
>   and replacing each pack expansion parameter with its
>   *`i`*<sup>th</sup> element. [...]

Therefore, `(enums >>= ...)` is semantically equivalent to `(A >>= (B >>= C))` when you instantiate it.  So this is a bug in Clang.